# Python beaver service not starting on RHEL 70

Tags: python, rhel7

I have installed python-beaver on RHEL7.0 but it does not start

```
/bin/systemctl start beaver.service
Job for beaver.service failed. See 'systemctl status beaver.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

But after this failure i see that the service is running

```
[root@Rhel70 ~]# ps -ef | grep beaver
beaver   57950     1  0 14:20 ?        00:00:00 /opt/stack/venvs/bin/python     /opt/stack/venvs/bin/beaver -c /etc/beaver/conf
beaver   57953 57950  0 14:20 ?        00:00:00 /opt/stack/venvs/bin/python     /opt/stack/venvs/bin/beaver -c /etc/beaver/conf
beaver   57955 57953  0 14:20 ?        00:00:00 /opt/stack/venvs/bin/python     /opt/stack/venvs/bin/beaver -c /etc/beaver/conf
root     57966 16540  0 14:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto beaver
```

The beaver start script is below, beaver.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Beaver Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
Restart=always
User=beaver
ExecStart=/opt/stack/venvs/bin/beaver -c /etc/beaver/conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: And what is the output of `systemctl status beaver.service`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem out. This was because i was using:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
```

Type=notify: identical to Type=simple, but with the stipulation that the daemon will send a signal to systemd when it is ready

This was not sending a signal though the service had started.

For more information:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd